# How to re-initialize the Google Test Framework

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest

Continueing from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401618/insert-an-element-to-a-vector-at-run-time-c-throwing-runtime-error).

The requirment is for Google Test.
Once I google test tracks Teast case `"Rasmi"`. It should re-run `Hi` then it will run `Rasmi`.
Making things clear:-

```
vect.push_back("Hello"); 
vect.push_back("Hi"); 
vect.push_back("Rasmi"); 
for(vect<string>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it) 
{  
if(*it == "Rasmi") // If it encounters "Rasmi"     
{ 
//it--;    
int index = it - vect.begin ();       
vect.insert(vect.begin()+2, "Hi");  
it = vect.begin () + index;    
}    
cout << *it; 
}
```

In this case when it reruns testcase `Hi` it just copies and pasted the previous executed test case. That is why test case `Rasmi` fails. But if all runs with out any conditions like

```
Hello->Hi->Rasmi... The execution becomes successful.
```

Please help me how to reinitialize GoogleTest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using singletons, then there could be something left over from the previous test (we have this problem where I currently work).

How about each test cleans up any changes it made to global objects before exiting?

Comment: No, there are no changes happening before and after exiting